# Execute task with build task

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I have a traditional java project using gradle build system.
I would like to add jacoco code coverage report generation. So I applied jacoco plugin and everything works as expected when I call `gradle build jacocoTestReport`

I was wondering how can I define in my `build.gradle` script that `jacocoTestReport` task should run automatically after `build`task has been finished.

The goal is to only run `gradle build` from command line and this will automatically execute `test` and `jacocoTestReport` (so that I don't have to pass `jacocoTestReport` as commandline parameter explicitly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to the end of your buildscript

```
build.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

Comment: think of gradle asking each task what its dependencies are (i.e. what needs to be run) before it can be run. "before build can be run, x must run", so "build depends on x"

Comment: Doing this in gradle 5.0 with Kotlin DSL fails as it cannot find 'build'.  Having a hard time finding the proper syntax to reference the build lifecycle phases like build, test, clean, etc.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest

```
build.finalizedBy(jacocoTestReport)
```

This way, the `jacocoTestReport` task is only executed after the build task, as you specified. In the accepted answer, the build task depends on the test report task, which means build will be executed *after* your custom task.

Comment: @sockeqwe According to asked question, this should be accepted answer. Thank you Denis.